# Raw type predicate causes compilation error

Tags: java, predicate

I don't understand why raw type `Predicate` causes compilation error even if I have a type cast. Let's look at the following example:

From a list containing different objects get the ones which extend `Number`, cast to a `Number` and collect to a `List`.

```
List<Object> objectList = Arrays.asList(1, 3.4, 2, new Object(), "");

List<Number> numbers = objectList
        .stream()
        .filter(Number.class::isInstance)
        .map(Number.class::cast)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Let's do the same thing, but this time let's cast `Number.class::isInstance` to `Predicate`:

```
List<Number> numbers1 = objectList.stream()
                .filter((Predicate) Number.class::isInstance)
                .map(Number.class::cast)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This leads to a compilation error:

> Error:(28, 25) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be
>   converted to java.util.List

There is a cast after a `filter` operation `.map(Number.class::cast)` and `.collect(Collectors.toList());`But the final type is `java.lang.Object`. Why do you think the result type is `java.lang.Object` and not a `List<Number>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As you've supplied a raw type to `filter`, it returns a raw `Stream`.
2. Ordinarily, `map` would be `<R> Stream<R> Stream<T>::map(Function<? super T, ?
   super R> function)`.  But now there is no `T`, so the argument is forced to be a raw `Function` type, so `map` too ends up returning a raw `Stream`.
3. Similar logic means that `collect` returns an `Object`.